# R caret randomforest

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Using the defaults of the train in caret package, I am trying to train a random forest model for the dataset xtr2 (dim(xtr2): 765 9408). The problem is that it unbelievably takes too long (more than one day for one training) to fit the function. As far as I know train in its default uses bootstrap sampling (25 times) and three random selection of mtry, so why it should take so long?
Please notice that I need to train the rf, three times in each run (because I need to make a mean of the results of different random forest models with the same data), and it takes about three days, and I need to run the code for 10 different samples, so it would take me 30 days to have the results.

My question is how I can make it faster?

1. Can changing the defaults of train make the operation time less? for example using CV for training?
2. Can parallel processing with caret package help? if yes, how it can be done?
3. Can tuneRF of random forest package make any changes to the time?

This is the code:

```
rffit=train(xtr2,ytr2,method="rf",ntree=500)
rf.mdl =randomForest(x=xtr2,y=as.factor(ytr2),ntree=500,
                     keep.forest=TRUE,importance=TRUE,oob.prox =FALSE ,
                     mtry = rffit$bestTune$mtry)
```

Thank you,

Comment: can you share your sample dataset?

Comment: `dim(xtr2): 765 9408` what does it mean?

Comment: What takes 24 hours: `train` or `randomForest` ? What is the value of `rffit$bestTune$mtry` ?  Did you try to call randomForest or train on same parameters on small samples of the data (say 50 elements) and see what is going on?  Did you try, on these small samples, play with parameters: keep.forest, importance, oob.prox, mtry?

Comment: @sandipan ,yes, I am looking where I can share the data ?

Comment: @user31264: the train  is the bottleneck, and rffit$bestTune$mtry is 9407...

Comment: 765 9408 are number of rows and columns of the data

Comment: yes, more or less I have tried, but i am not sure what u mean to look for..

Comment: you can dput your sample data along with the code itself

Comment: @ sandipan: http://www.filedropper.com/xtr2 ,  http://www.filedropper.com/ytr2

Comment: Please use these two links for dl the data

Comment: The default `ntree=500` is generally overkill, but especially here with only 765 rows! Reduce it to ntree=3,5,whatever

Comment: this is matlab data file, are you using R.matlab to read it?

Comment: You don't need to do CV in randomForest because OOB CV is done in the building process. `caret` does 10-fold CV by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thoughts on your questions:

1. Yes! But don't forget you also have control over the search grid `caret` uses for the tuning parameters; in this case, `mtry`. I'm not sure what the default search grid is for `mtry`, but try the following:

   ctrl <- trainControl("cv", number = 5, verboseIter = TRUE)

   set.seed(101)  # for reproducibility

   rffit <- train(xtr2, ytr2, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 5)
2. Yes! See the `caret` website: http://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel-processing.html
3. Yes and No! `tuneRF` simply uses the OOB error to find an optimal value  of `mtry` (the only tuning parameter in `randomForest`). Using cross-validation tends to work better and produce a more honest estimate of model performance. `tuneRF` can take a long time but should be quicker than k-fold cross-validation.

Overall, the online manual for `caret` is quite good: http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You use `train` for determining `mtry` only.  I would skip the `train` step, and stay with default `mtry`:

```
rf.mdl =randomForest(x=xtr2,y=as.factor(ytr2),ntree=500,
                    keep.forest=TRUE,importance=TRUE,oob.prox =FALSE)
```

I strongly doubt that 3 different runs is a good idea.

If you do 10 fold cross-validation (I am not sure it should be done anyways, as validation is ingrained into the random forest), 10 parts is too much, if you are short in time.  5 parts would be enough.

Finally, the time of randomForest is proportional to nTree.  Set nTree=100, and your program will run 5 time faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would also just add, that it the main issue is speed, there are several other random forest implementations in `caret`, and many of them are much faster than the original `randomForest` which is notoriously slow.  I've found `ranger` to be a nice alternative that suited my very simple needs.

Here is a nice [summary of the random forest packges in R](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/different-random-forest-packages-r-madhur-modi). Many of these are in `caret` already.

Also for consideration, here's an interesting [study of the performance of `ranger` vs `rborist`](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281144987_ranger_A_Fast_Implementation_of_Random_Forests_for_High_Dimensional_Data_in_C_and_R/figures), where you can see how performance is affected by the tradeoff between sample size and features.